# How to get post type archive category title

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I'm getting tired and confused so thought I would ask here before quitting for the day.

I have created a custom post type of `membercontent`

Under `membercontent` I have created the taxonomy `membercontent_category`

In the archive.php I was re-writing the title with:

```
                    ...

                    elseif ( is_post_type_archive( 'membercontent' ) ) :

                        _e( 'Member Content', 'radiate' );                      

                    elseif ( get_post_type() == 'membercontent' ) :

                        post_type_archive_title();

                    else :

                        _e( 'Archives', 'radiate' );

                    endif;
```

This however does not show the category archive pages...

is there a get_category_title() function?

Answer (score 0):

```
$category_detail=get_the_category(get_the_ID());//$post->ID
                                foreach($category_detail as $cd)
                                {
                                    $name_category=$cd->cat_name;
                                    $id_category=$cd->term_id;
                                    echo $name_category;

                                }
```

> this code get category name and id  you just put a post id